# write a code that executes in all states?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to ping a service. I want to ping this service at regular intervals . What I want is this code should be running in all states except for a few ones.

This is what I am doing now :

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state,$ionicPopup,$ionicHistory, $timeout, $rootScope, connectivityMonitor) {


    $rootScope.isAppOnline = function() {
        var is_connected = connectivityMonitor.isInternetConnected();
        is_connected.then(function(result) {
                 //some code to call a webservice

        });
    }

    $timeout(function(){
        var currentStateName = $ionicHistory.currentStateName();
        console.log("currentStateName == ",currentStateName);
        $rootScope.isAppOnline();
    },10000);
```

The problem is isApponline function is called only once.
But I want it to keep pinging every 10 seconds on all the screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$interval` rather than `$timeout`.

`$timeout` is for executing a function once in the future. `$interval` is for executing a function at regular intervals.

Note that there's no need to add this function to the $rootScope.